# Append Not working in StringBuilder in Java It says "method append(char) is undefined for the type StringBuilder"

Tags: java

```
public class StringBuilder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(char ch='a'; ch<='z'; ch++){
            sb.append(ch);
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling your custom class `StringBuilder`, which collides with a core Java class of the same name?  Your code should be working, other than this potential problem.

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: It says " method append(char) is undefined for the type StingBuilder"