# charAt() and str.length() showing undefined for the typeerror

Tags: java, string

```
public class String {

    public static boolean palindrome(String str){

        for(int i=0; i<str.length()/2; i++){

          if(str.charAt(i)!=str.charAt(str.length()-1-i)){

            return false;

          }

        }   

        return true;

     }

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    String str = "racecar";

    System.out.println(palindrome(str));

  }
}
```

charAt() and str.length() isn't working and showing errors. I don't know how to fix it? I'm currently learning DSA

Comment: Why did you define `class String`? There is already built in class String.

Comment: **Don not** give your own classes the same names as classes from the standard library.

Comment: I think mistake here is defining custom class with the same name as one of the built in classes. In this case, it's `class String`. Now whenever you try to use built in class String, it won't work because you 'redefined' it with your custom class and all methods that were defined for built in class String won't work.

Comment: BTW to use the standard `String` you *could* use `java.lang.String` instead of just `String` -- but anyway it is strongly recommended to NOT name a class with the same name as standard class, even more regarding such basic classes like `String`, `System`, ... - this will mostly cause confusion!

Comment: More precisely a duplicate of [Append Not working in StringBuilder in Java It says "method append(char) is undefined for the type StringBuilder" \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73432347/append-not-working-in-stringbuilder-in-java-it-says-method-appendchar-is-unde).

Answer (score 3):

You have created another class String, that shadows the java.lang.String, and you're trying to take `String[] args` in the main() method, where String is now your class, not java.lang.String. Also, you're taking **your** String in the palindrome method, and the errors occur because your class String doesn't have methods length, charAt, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is `public class String { ...` .
Using other name to replace `String` will solve the problem. E.g.

```
public class MyString {
   //...
}
```